# IE 10 cuts off text in text box after 100 px

Tags: css, input, textbox, internet-explorer-10

I have text boxes that specify with inline CSS that their width should be 200px

```
<input type="text" name="xxx" value="yyy" style="width: 200px;" />
```

IE 10 presents them as below (highlighted where text is cut off)

[image]

As soon as that textbox receives focus, all the text becomes visible (and then after it has lost focus again, **the text remains visible**)

Anybody have the same problem and manage to fix this?

Comment: I Tried this in IE10 http://jsfiddle.net/qDTWw/1/ - I don't see text being cut off

Answer (score 5):

I'm 99% sure this has something to do with the "clear button" in ie10.

When a textbox gets focus in ie10 a little "x" appears on the right side that allows you to clear the text.

You can remove the x by adding this to the stylesheet

```
::-ms-clear {
display: none;
}
```

Chances are there is something messing with the style of the clear button.  I would suggest adding the style I pasted above and see if that fixes your issue.

Here's a fiddle that kinda replicates your issue (with bad css)

http://jsfiddle.net/qDTWw/3/

Here's a fiddle with the fix

http://jsfiddle.net/qDTWw/4/

Comment: I tried that as part of my attempts, because someone else said that worked, but it didn't make any difference for me. Also, the jsFiddle examples aren't replicating the problem for either.

Comment: The fact that there's no 'x' in your capture leads me to believe that this is the case.  As I mentioned there might be some css already in place that is breaking this.

Answer (score 4):

I am getting the same in a password box in ie10
This workaround seems to work for me ...

```
$('.password').blur(function () {
    //work around for ie10 clipping text
    $(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Haha. That also works if I just run it on the console, without the blur. Guess I could write a hack that on every page after load, runs through all input boxes, and sets the value of the box to itself. I really hope it doesn't come to that.

Answer (score 2):

*This isn't a true "*answer*", because I haven't solved it, but am posting here with additional information that won't fit into a comment very well. I have this same problem, and am hoping this helps someone else figure it out.

This jsfiddle is one way to reproduce the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/2NGEQ/2/

Apparently, this was reported to Microsoft:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/767602/input-text-boxes-clipped-when-a-font-size-is-applied-to-a-parent-element#details

There is a reference to a reply from someone at Microsoft here:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8677
 *From Tony Ross (Microsoft):
    Unfortunately I don’t think this will make our bar for a patch update since the issue automatically resolves itself when the user interacts with the control, but I’ll definitely make sure it stays on our radar for the next release.
    As for code-based workarounds, there are various ways you can poke the input element itself to get it to it to update if you so desire (updating the value, changing the width of the element inline, assigning the width inline to begin with, etc).....*

Posting code from jsfiddle [because I have to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by tj_vantoll</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">  
  <style type='text/css'>
    input { width: 150px; }
form.on input { font-size: 1em; }
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
   $('form').addClass('on');
});
});//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="Whatever" />
</form>
<button>Break It</button>  
</body>
</html
```